# How can I set breakpoint to [DataMember] property

Tags: c#

I have a 'Serializable' class and it has 'DataMember' properties. 
How can I set breakpoint when MyProperty is set?
I try 'Data Breakpoint' in VS, but it is disabled.

```
[Serializable]
[DataContract]
public class MyClass
{
    [DataMember]
    public bool MyProperty{ get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you expand your property to the full definition

```
private bool myVar;

        public bool MyProperty
        {
            get { return myVar; }
            set { myVar = value; }
        }
```

you should be able to set breakpoints on the `get` and `set` methods.